# how can i get input while it show list out of index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

the code->[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZnhT.png)
the error->[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chaQi.png)
I can't get inputs it's showing List index out of range

```py
n = int(input())
a = []
temp = input().split()
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(temp[i]))
print(a)
```

Comment: What inputs do you supply to your program?

Comment: i'm getting integers as input

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of these integers?

Comment: `n` and `len(temp)` need to align. At the moment it looks like you `n` is larger

Comment: I gave n=4
and started to give the inputs
but after giving first value
it shows list index out of range

Comment: after giving the first value did you hit return and thus end the user input?

Comment: Please update your question with the full stacktrace, including the prompts and your inputs.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow i don't know what to do!!

Comment: Ok, but how do you know that you had a `list index out of range`?

Comment: Ok, you've just changed your code. I don't know what's going on any more. Please update your question with the *actual text* of both the code *and* the error traceback.

Comment: @JonSG yes i did hit return. 
just now understand that i need to give the inputs with spaces,  what i did wrong is i've pressed return after giving the first input.
Thank you for your answer JonSG

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```py
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
print(a)
```

Comment: i know this method.
but i seen the above code in a online test.
when tried to execute it, it shows error

Answer (score 0):

According to your input, which was "4" and "2",
n = 4
temp = [2]

Then, the length of the list is 1
len(temp) = 1

I'm not sure what exactly you need from your code, but you can do it this way:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(min(n, len(temp))):
    a.append(int(input()))
print(a)
```

Or you can also use exceptions:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    try:
        a.append(int(input()))
    except IndexError:
        break
print(a)
```